# iCEstick40HX1K device is malfunctioned, and windows does not recognize it when programming bitstream on Diamond Programmer 3.5

Tags: fpga, programmer, lattice

I'd designed a " SPI Flash Erase, program,verify with iCEstick 40HX1K. I programmed on Diamond Programmer 3.5. it had done successfully only one time.then i want to reprogram, but when I connect it to my laptop again I see the following message: "USB device not recognized"[image]

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? 
is the iCEstick device damaged?

Note: I run on windowns 8.1 64bit

Comment: Please format your code and add the lattice-diamond tag!

Comment: Please post your pin assignment in code tags. Have you programmed the SPI flash, CRAM, NVCM? You might have created a short within your fpga device description.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with "USB device not recognized" as well but with the "MachXO3L Starter Kit". After a lot of research and a not very helpful response from the Lattice technical service I figured it out:
The USB bridge IC (FT2232H) needs a 12 MHz clock to function properly. This clock signal is generated by a oscillator which is connected to the FT2232H **AND** the FPGA. Accidently I added a clock output in my design and did not assign a fixed pad/pin for it. By chance Diamond placed this clock output exactly on the 12 MHz clock. Due to the interference the FT2232H malfunctioned.

Solution: remove the shunt/0Ohm resistor between 12 MHz clock and FPGA pin. In the case of "MachXO3L Starter Kit" it is R23. If you have a oscilloscope around you can easily measure the frequency of the clock to check if the very same thing happend to you.